# Proper way to create an observable that reads a value once and returns it many times

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have an Angular app that includes a service for reading runtime configuration using HTTP (`EnvironmentConfigService`), and another service (`UrlManagerService`) that uses the data from that service to compute the URLs for various services and provide them to the rest of the application.

The way I want this to behave is: the `UrlManagerService` reads the configuration when the app starts up, and it provides a method that callers use to get the computed URLs via an observable. If the HTTP request is still in progress, the observable emits when the request completes; if the request has already completed, the observable immediately emits the data that is in memory.

The code currently looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EnvironmentConfigService } from './environment-config.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UrlManagerService {
    // it has public properties for all of the URLs

    private configLoaded: Observable<UrlManagerService>;

    constructor(private configService: EnvironmentConfigService) {
        this.configLoaded = this.configService
            .read()
            .map(config => {
                // compute URLs and assign to properties
                return this;
            });
        this.configLoaded.subscribe(() => {
            this.configLoaded = Observable.of(this)
        });
    }

    public getInitialized(): Observable<UrlManagerService> {
        return this.configLoaded;
    }
}
```

The `getInitialized` method returns the observable for the HTTP request (returned by `EnvironmentConfigService.read`) when it is in progress; once the data has been read, it changes to using a static observable created using `Observable.of`.

The main concerns I have are:

1. Do I need to switch over to using the static observable or can I just keep using the observable from the HTTP request (I don't want the HTTP request to be re-executed on subsequent `subscribe` calls).
2. If the static observable is required, do I need to unsubscribe from the HTTP observable?
3. Is there a standard way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `AsyncSubject`, see [What's the point of AsyncSubject in RXJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306877/whats-the-point-of-asyncsubject-in-rxjs/)

```
@Injectable()
export class UrlManagerService {

  private configLoaded = new AsyncSubject<UrlManagerService>();

  constructor(private configService: EnvironmentConfigService) {
    this.configService
      .read()
      .map(config => {
        // compute URLs and assign to properties
        return this;
      })
      .subscribe(this.configLoaded) // pass the result and the 'complete' notification
  }

  public getInitialized(): Observable<UrlManagerService> {
    return this.configLoaded.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: However, `AsyncSubject` will also cache errors if the call errored.

Comment: Indeed, to retry with `AsyncSubject` requires a new AsyncSubject. Not as succinct as `.shareReplay(1)`.

Comment: While my tests indicate that the `publishReplay.refCount` and `shareReplay` approaches both work, the documentation for both indicates that they both end when there are no more observers. On the other hand, the documentation for `AsyncSubject` indicates that it is intended for exactly what I am doing, so I'm accepting this response. Two notes: `AsyncSubject` inherits from `Observable`, so the `asObservable` call is not necessary; also, the syntax for instantiating `configLoaded` is incorrect. I've fixed both of those.

Comment: **the asObservable call is not necessary** - that is true, what it does is stop functions using `getInitialized()` from calling `.next()` on it. It's a convention, thought I should include it.

Comment: I see. The documentation for it was not particularly informative, but after thinking about it, I assume that the intent is to prevent callers from casting back to `AsyncSubject` and modifying it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shareReplay(1)` to multicast the observable over a ReplaySubject. Unlike `publishReplay(1).refCount()`, this will keep the cache even if there are no subscribers at some point. It is still retryable on errors, which makes it perfect for this.

```
return this.configService.read()
  .shareReplay(1);
```

However, you need rxjs 5.5.0 or later as there was an important bugfix for this.

Comment: This is a better method than `AsyncSubject`.

Answer (score 1):

1) You may keep using the http observable. Just do something like:

```
this.configLoaded = this.configService
        .read()
        .map(config => {
            // compute URLs and assign to properties
            return this;
        })
        .publishReplay(1)
        .refCount();
```

.publishReplay(1) -> caches the most recent value.

.refCount() -> keeps the observable as long as there are subscribers.

2) Once the http request is finished, it completes itself, so there is no need for unsubscribing.

Comment: Regarding `refCount`, subscribers will come and go during the lifecycle of the application as service calls are made by the users of `UrlManagerService`. So I need to keep the observable alive indefinitely.

Comment: I think if you provide `UrlManagerService` in `app.module` you will get a singleton that persists it's values (need to test to be sure).

Comment: Oh, sorry - you're saying if all subscribers unsubscribe at some point you will loose the value.

Comment: Perhaps then a `ReplaySubject` is the way to go.

Comment: I just read some articles, the documentation says that refCount will keep it alive until all subscribers have unsubscribed. However, it seems that you can reconnect even after that. You should give it a try, it may work for you.